# regexp to check if characters match string

Tags: php, regex

I have some input string with characters and list of string. What I need is to select only strings that meet pattern that contains characters.
For excample:

input chars = "ask"
it should accept "ask", "sak", "kas"...
but should not accept "akk", "aas"...

now I use pattern like "^[s|a|k][s|a|k][s|a|k]$"
but probablem with it that it accept and repeated characters ("akk"), so if I using this I need some additional check if preg_match works.

What it makes a bit more complicated, that there can be few same characters:
input "askk"
should match "akks", but not "kkks" or "assk".

I believe that this check can be done with single regexp, but my knowledge about regexp isn't so deep.

(to get input and show resuls I use php)

Comment: This really sounds like something regexes aren't suited for. Just count how many times each character appears in each pattern using a loop; it'll be both easier to read and easier to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using a regex here? I don't see the benefit. What you could do is sort the input string (e.g. both 'sak' and 'ask' will turn into 'aks') and compare that sorted string to a reference string, 'aks' in this case. Or just use the same function on the reference string 'ask' as well. Something like this:

```php
function str_sort($str) {
    $chars = str_split($str);
    sort($chars);
    return implode('', $chars);
}

$pattern = 'ask';
$input = 'sak';
$valid = str_sort($pattern) == str_sort($input);

echo "Pattern: $pattern;\n";
echo "Input  : $input\n";
echo "Valid  : " . ($valid ? 'yes' : 'no') . "\n";
```

Comment: regexp was just first try, because usually it's powerfull enough. And input can contain something like 'any char', but of course it could be done in other way, maybe even more elegant. Just in past when I was need text search regexp helped.

Comment: Oh I love regular expressions, but in this situation, it's just not the most elegant solution. For every pattern you'd want to check against, you'd have to write a non-trivial regex, which isn't really worth the trouble in my opinion. Just look at some of the other answers to see what I mean. Just because it's possible doesn't mean it needs to be done. But you figured that out by yourself already it seems :)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually pretty hard to solve that sort of problem using regular expressions. You can do it if you have lookahead expressions. Here's an example, where `(?=...)` is a lookahead expression.

```
/^(?=.*a)(?=.*s)(?=.*k).{3}$/
```

Here each of the `(?=.*a)` expressions match that letter, anywhere in the expression, and the .{3} specifies that it must be three characters.

This becomes complicated when you have duplicate characters, but it's still possible. For `aask`:

```
/^(?=.*a.*a)(?=.*s)(?=.*k).{4}$/
```

Where the first one matches only if there are two `a`s anywhere in the string.

You can do this a few other ways. For example, you can iterate over each character and count the number of each letter, storing it in an array (which is O(n)), or you can sort the characters alphabetically (`aks`) and match the strings character by character (which is O(whatever your sorting algorithm is)).

Comment: thanks for answer. I hope this way will solve search problem, if not, maybe will need rethink that search algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for "askk":

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*s)(?=(?:.*k){2})[ask]{4}$
```

The idea is to use lookaheads to make sure the correct number of each character exists in the string first, and then consume the rest of the string ensuring that only characters in the provided set are used.

[See it working on Rubular.](http://www.rubular.com/r/F0BX8hr8tr)